# MonoTouch binding issue of inheriting abstract member

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am working on [MonoTouch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#MonoTouch) binding of an Objective-C application. I referred *[iOS Binding Walkthrough](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough)*.

I have generated libraries for i386, [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) and then a universal library. Further, I created a MonoTouch Binding Project. I have generated ApiDefinition using Sharpie and added the universal library generated earlier. Now when I build this project I am getting the following error.

> ADClusterAnnotation.g.cs(86,86): Error CS0533: 
>  AnnotationClusterMap.ADClusterAnnotation.Coordinate' hides inherited abstract member MonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation.Coordinate' (CS0533)

Here is the code snippet of ADClusterAnnotation:

#### File ADClusterannotation.h

```
@interface ADClusterAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  _coordinates;   
}
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@end
```

#### File ADClusterAnnotation.m

```
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinates;
```

Here is the code snippet from ApiDefinition

```cs
[BaseType (typeof (MKAnnotation))]
public partial interface ADClusterAnnotation {
    [Export ("coordinate")]
    CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate { get; set; }
}
```

So I think we need to change something in ApiDefinition. I tried removing Coordinate from ADClusterAnnotation in the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) definition, but then it gives an error that it implements an abstract member. What am I missing with regard to Monotouch binding?

Answer (score 2):

Overriding an abstract member require `c#` `new` or `override`

You can get that to be generated by changing your ApiDefinition to:

```cs
[BaseType (typeof (MKAnnotation))]
public partial interface ADClusterAnnotation {
    [Export ("coordinate")]
    [New]
    CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why "new" or "override" is required here? I cannot see how some ObjC code could have an "abstract" method. Or is it because the property is already in the managed MKAnnotation?

Comment: `MKAnnotation` in `Xamarin.iOS` define `Coordinate` as `abstract`: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation.Coordinate. If you want to override an abstract member, you have to mark it `new` or `override`. That's what the `[New]` attribute does.